# ddply shiny summaise input$

Tags: r, shiny, plyr

I have a data.frame with columns `gender` (levels= male, female) and `smoke` (levels=no,yes).
I would like to create a new data.frame by:

```
final_data <- ddply(scores_data, c("gender","smoke"),
                            summarise, n = length(gender))
```

This works! But I want:

```
final_data <- ddply(data.frame, c(input$variable_1,input$variable_2), 
                      summarise, n = length(input$variable_1))
```

The problem is here: `n = length(input$variable_1))` - if a replace `input$variable_1` per gender it works, otherwise `n` is always equal to 1.

Thanks.

Comment: It is very unclear your goal and even if someone get it, he/she can't help you in my opinion. Please do post a piece of your data and a desired output to allow us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
myFunction2 <- function(x, y, col){
      z <- ddply(x, c(y,col), .fun = function(xx){
        c(n = length(xx[,col])) })
      return(z)
    }

final_data =  myFunction2(data.frame, input$variable_1, input$variable_1)
```